# Как получить соответствующую дату?

Tags: python, datetime

Всем привет! Есть такая задача, необходимо написать на Python:
Нужно создать две переменные

Первая переменная - дата 00:00 часов прошедшего дня в формате unix time

Вторая переменная - дата 23:59 часов прошедшего дня в формате unix time.

То есть, к примеру, я запускаю прямо сейчас файл python и получаю 00:00 25.12.2018 в формате unix time. Так как сегодня 26.12.2018, я получаю вчерашний день.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопросе пример кодом

Comment: @gil9red , тут даже пример кодом не получится привести. Я поэтому и не писал код) Думаю, вполне понятен вопрос. Могу уточнить, если необходима какая-то информация.

Comment: @Gatsby зря не писали код. смысл этого сообщества помочь с решением проблемы, а не выполнять за вас задания. Так что, напишите, чего добились сами и укажите, что конкретно не получается. Если конкретно не получается вообще ничего - то вам нужно начать с учебника по Python.

Comment: Гуглите, как работать с datetime, там есть всё, что вам нужно.

Comment: [Unix time](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) - количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи (00:00:00 UTC) 1 января 1970 года (четверг); этот момент называют «эпохой Unix» (англ. Unix Epoch). Вы хотите это *количество секунд* в ваших 2 переменных?

Comment: @MarianD , да. Всё верно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для верности я включил тоже строковой формат.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
one_day =  datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = today - one_day

time1 = datetime.time(0)         # 00:00
time2 = datetime.time(23, 59)    # 23:59

date_time_1 = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday, time1)
date_time_2 = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday, time2)

str_1 = date_time_1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
str_2 = date_time_2.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

unix_1 = date_time_1.timestamp()
unix_2 = date_time_2.timestamp()

print(str_1)
print(str_2)

print()

print(unix_1)
print(unix_2)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 26.12.2018 00:00
> 26.12.2018 23:59
>
> 1545778800.0
> 1545865140.0
> ```

Comment: Привет! Огромное спасибо за ответ. У меня такой вопрос - в онлайн конвертере timestamp число 1545778800 (unix_1) будет время 2018-12-25T23:00:00+00:00

А unix_2 будет 2018-12-26T22:59:00+00:00

Почему так?

Comment: Потому что ваше *локальное время* отличается от *UTC* (всемирного координированного время) *на 1 час*. (Пока у вас 23:59, UTC будет 22:59, пока у вас 00:00, в UTC будет 23:00 предыдущего дня.)

Comment: А можно это как-то конвертировать в дату по Мск?

Comment: Не нужно ничего конвертировать, т.к.я пологаю, что в вашей операционной системе уже выбрано московское время (UTC+3). UNIX time всегда вычисляется из UTC, и так в вашем онлайн конвертере будут результаты на 3 часа меньше.